AvatarView with the MAUI CommunityToolKit show scaling images
In my NET8 MAUI project, I'm using the MAUI Community Toolkit to display an avatar. Usually, I display only letters but occasionally also images. For that, I wrote this
<toolkit:AvatarView
    Grid.RowSpan="2"
    ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"
    BackgroundColor="{Binding LetterBackgroundColor}"
    Text="{Binding FirstLetter}"
    TextColor="{Binding LetterColor}" />

This is working but when it displays images, those are not scaling properly. Here is an example.

Is there a way to centre and scale the image?
Update
This is the result on Android.

It is different from the Windows result above but it is still not the best view.

What platform do you use?  Right now  I can reproduce this on Windows. But works fine on Android and iOS.

The first screenshot is from the Windows version. Now, I updated the post with the Android result: quite a similar result as Windows.

I don't quite understand. What's the difference between the three images?  Are they using different image source?

Yes, there 3 different images with the same size. What I like to do is to centre the image in the circle and fit their aspect.

Yes, Android works much better than Windows. You may raise an issue on GitHub.
